# bitmapFactory.decodefile giving null as output

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.sugandhabansal.gallerypickimage;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int SELECTED_PIC = 1;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    public void btnClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECTED_PIC);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECTED_PIC:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                    String filepath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
                    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(), bitmap);
                    imageView.setBackground(drawable);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the MainActivity.java file. The code basically loads a image from gallery  and displays it in imageview section of the layout. 
When I ran the apk on my smartphone, no image was seen in imageview section after selection and after debugging it was seen that bitmap is equal to null. 
Can someone please help me with this problem as I'm unable to solve it.

Comment: Check what is in filepath string, comment out bitmap factory and all relevant code to it. A simple toast on filepath will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure the obtained file path is a valid path.
- Make sure you have the permissions to access storage.

If above things are okay and you still get null result, try following code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
```